# How do I compile multiple css files and javascript files into one file?

Tags: css, webpack, compilation, bundling-and-minification, css-import

I'm going through a wordpress theme building tutorial and was given a folder, https://github.com/t-hoff-94/university-static,  with a JavaScript folder and a CSS folder, and also a 'bundled' file for each type that I am linking to for the actual project. I am trying to figure out how they compiled the code so I don't have to modify the bundled file and I can replicate the set-up. All I want is to be able to have multiple files to organize code, and I am curious how they imported "3rd party packages".

I have searched for ways to do this with webpack but most of it seemed to be injecting the css into a JavaScript file, or the style tag in the heading.

Comment: You don't. The CSS and Javascript need to have different `Content-Type` in HTTP parlance

Comment: Sorry i'm not sure what you mean by that. I'm wondering how they generated the bundled CSS file from the CSS folder, and the bundled JS file from the JS folder. https://github.com/t-hoff-94/university-static, is the exact project i'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there were using `webpack` according to [this file](https://github.com/t-hoff-94/university-static/blob/master/js/scripts-bundled.js) for example. But the whole thing is missing the actual config.

Comment: Ok that helps. Am I able to achieve this with "ExtractTextWebpackPlugin"?

Comment: Actually `ExtractTextWebpackPlugin` is deprecated now in Webpack 4. Writing a webpack config from scratch is quite a daunting task.